# What kind of object am I creating here?

Tags: javascript, object

I see many sites trying to prevent scope pollution by creating and populating a single object. For example:

```
var $ = {}
$.something = function() {
   ...
};
```

But I am wondering about the follow initialisation:

```
var $ = function() {
    // Something
}
$.something_two = function...
```

Is there any difference between the two and does the second code initialise a class instance upon each call?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I may have missed the point of your question: This article provides a good explanation of object creation in JS: https://medium.com/dailyjs/instantiation-patterns-in-javascript-8fdcf69e8f9b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript all values, except primitives, are objects.

Ran my own version of your code to help demonstrate:

[image]

Also note the types of the objects created. In your first example `$` is an `object` which contains the function(s). In the second, `$` is a function (object) with a property which is also a function:

[image]

Either option would be ideal for preventing scope pollution, the first example is the most consistent with object creation standards.